# Custom WooCommerce login and registration redirection for one page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication, woocommerce

I would like my WooCommerce login and registration form to redirect to a specific page *(after login/registration)*, but only when the user is on a specific login page.

I have added the following code in my `functions.php` file:

```
if (is_page(6432)) {
    add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
    function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
        $redirect_to = 'http://www.eliv.com.tw/product/tripsignup';
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
```

The function works without the `if (is_page(6432))` on all pages. But I Would like to make this function only work on page 6432.

Also I want to adapt it for registration but so far I couldn't get this to work.

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add  the condition inside your function, this way (without any guaranty):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
    if (is_page(6432))
        $redirect_to = home_url('/product/tripsignup/');

    return $redirect_to;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*